# What are the exact packages required to connect to Azure Storage from Python?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm confused by the deprecation warnings of a bunch of packages. I've been uninstalling and re-installing a bunch of packages to no avail. My script is throwing an error on this line: `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient`

And the resulting error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\dir\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient'
```

Output from `pip freeze` for Azure-related packages are:

```
adal==1.2.2
azure-common==1.1.25
azure-core==1.4.0
azure-identity==1.3.1
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage==0.36.0
azure-storage-common==2.1.0
```

Am I missing something? I've seen some people with `azure-storage-common` and also installed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you would want to install is `azure-storage-blob`. That package has `BlobServiceClient`, `BlobClient`, `ContainerClient`.

You can get more information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python and here's the link to the API reference documentation for the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that running `pip install azure-storage` would take care of any packages starting with `azure-storage`.

Comment: No. `azure-storage` is the older version of the package that had blobs, files, queues and tables support in a single package. The recent versions of the SDK has split blobs, files and queues in separate packages and dropped table support completely (as tables have moved to Cosmos DB).